# merge two arrayList list into one android

Tags: android

I want   merge two `arrayList` list into one 
list1 and list 2 contains 
`list1` : ahm,sam,ram
`list2` :1      1   0
i want to put the first position of list1 with first position to list 1 
ex: want to call `(ram,0) (ahm,1)` and so on....?

```
ArrayList<String> list1=new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<String> list2=new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: I dont really understand. Do you want the first entry of list1 to become "ahm,1"?

Comment: i don't understand the data structure of the output. also, what have you tried?

Comment: I mean i want to put the two elements at the same position in the two lists in one position in list 3!

Comment: check my edit, thought you wanted HashMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write a method to success what you want to do like:

```
String getPair( int position )
{
    return list1.get( position ) +","+ list2.get( position );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

So you want keys and values into one list? Then you will need a `HashMap` in order to get this:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++){
    myMap.put(list1.get(i), list2.get(i));
}
```

Edit: so you want to put two elements of each list into a new list, with `String` format as `(x,y)` then you need to do the following:

```
ArrayList<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++){
    // if list2 contains string represented with numbers
    String str = list1.get(i) + "," + list2.get(i); 
    // if list2 contains integers
    String str = list1.get(i) + "," + String.valueOf(list2.get(i)); 
    list3.add(str);
}
```

Comment: thanx for ur ans:) but crashes the  app:( actually i dont understand the concept of hasgMap!!

Answer (score 1):

I dont exacly know what you mean, but probably something like this: (assuming you have two equal sized lists)

```
for(int i=0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
  list1.get(i) = list1.get(i) + "," + list2(i);
}
```

However, if I understand correctly, you probably need a `HashMap`:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++){
  map.put(list1.get(i), list2.get(i));
}
```

For real merging, use list1.addAll(list2);

Comment: thanx for the ans but it gaves me an error that the map dosent match with 2 strings !! that put dosent take two strings ?!

Comment: @MeralAB if you want to save the 1 and 0 as String, just make the HashMap into HashMap<String, String>